# Adding events to Raphael elements

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael

Hey, I'm trying to add a mousemove and click event to an SVG Raphael Rectangle:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/nXKbW/1/

Code:

```
tile = ctx.rect(x*10,y*(i*10),10,10).attr({
    fill:'#000000',
    stroke: '#ffffff'
});
tile.mouseover(function(e) {
    pX = e.pageX;
    pY = e.pageY;
});
tile.click(function() {
    console.log('x: '+pX+'| y:'+pY);
});
```

Obviously, for some reason this doesn't function - I get no output onClick :'(

Comment: Sorry, it was obvious that u had seen them. The point is the variables dont have scope. checkt this out http://jsjoy.com/blog/10/raphael-js-adding-scoped-event-handlers

Comment: I've used the edited Raphael.js file from that link - but the handlers still aren't firing :(

Comment: Ok, hang on. Somehow your fiddle hangs both IE and firefox for me.

Comment: How strange, not sure why that is... It doesn't crash mine... FF4.0.1 and IE9

Comment: FF 3.6.17 drinks waay too much ram. I've copied it on to my system and i am working with it.

Comment: This is a Chrome experiment anyway, the event handlers is the real issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've got the click function to work. Finally ^_^.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* GLOBAL VARIABLES */
            var drawFrames;
            var canvas;
            var ctx;
            var universe = new Array();
            var tile;
            var pX,pY = 0;

            universe = (
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
            );

            /* WINDOW LOAD */
            window.onload = function() {
                init();
            }

            /* INITIALISATION */
            function init() {
                ctx = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
                drawFrames = setInterval(drawFrame, 40);
            }

            /* FRAME RENDER LOOP */
            function drawFrame() {
                //ctx.clear();
                for (var x = 0; x < universe.length; x++) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < universe[x].length; y++) {
                        for (var i= 0; i < 11; i++) {
                            tile = ctx.rect(x*10,y*(i*10),10,10).attr({
                                fill:'#000000',
                                stroke: '#ffffff'
                            }).click(function(e) {
                        console.log('x: '+e.pageX+'| y:'+e.pageY);
                        })
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="main" width="800" height="600">
            <h1>No Support I'm Afraid...</h1>
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It had to be for every element and not the entire set of rect elements thats why it wasn't firing properly.

Comment: Oh and the reason for the ram usage was due to that setInterval! If you use setTimeout that doesn't happen either :)

Answer (score 5):

first give your raphael object an id then bind the click event to it.

```
tile = ctx.rect(x*10,y*(i*10),10,10).attr({
fill:'#000000',
stroke: '#ffffff'
});
tile.node.id='tile_id';
$('#tile_id').bind('click',function(){alert('clicked');});
```